# Selecting a range that is from one cell to a found value?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm making some sparklines and I'm trying to reference a range for the source data.  The Problem is that the Range is added onto every month.  I need to be able to use a range from a known first cell to until it finds a value.Offset(0,-1)

```
Dif wb As Workbook 
Dif ws As Worksheet 

    Set wb = Workbooks("HardDrive location")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

wb.ws.Range.Rows(4).Cells.Find("XXX").Offset(0, 1).Select

Selection.SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkLine, SourceData:= Range("D4", wb.ws.Range.Rows(4).Find("XXX").Offset(0,-1))

'Other Parameters are below, but there aren't any problems past this point'
```

Not really sure how to get that to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Presumably you could set your range dynamically using wb.ws.Range.Rows(4).Cells.Find("XXX").Offset(0, 1).Address. Not sure from your wording exactly what you need to use as the range though.

Comment: Well, depending on where you stand on VBA & Excel, this may be too much of a stretch in terms of learning. However, I you are keen, I would strongly encourage you to learn about working with tables instead of raw ranges for this sort of things.

Tables will manage for you the active range, makes it easier to refer to specific columns by names, etc. They make VBA a lot easier to use as well....

Comment: @Francky_V Do you know of any good resources for learning this?

Comment: Sure are a few - a quick cheatsheet that I refer to once in a while is this one: http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables . It's good for the VBA part of using tables.

For the in-sheet formulas, that one is a good overview to start with:

http://peltiertech.com/structured-referencing-excel-tables/

Like many other excel things, the value-add becomes clearer with use. The main gain is flexibility: it keeps tracks of ranges & references for you, so no need for dirty $A$5:$B$15 anymore...

Comment: @TimEdwards I have an asset that records a value every month.  Rows are assets, and Columns are months.  After the last month of data (so at the end of the Row), Is a place holder column with the text "XXX" in a cell for each asset.  [**Here**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B-dIFNkGhDyDwW63k-eLlvV_93XBnPKRS5Qf0hn11L8/edit?usp=sharing) is a simplified version of the document.  The range I need to make Sparklines of is from the first value entered, to the cell before "XXX".  That way the spark lines will automatically adjust no matter how many months of data I have.

Comment: @Francky_V Thanks I'll have to read through this stuff when I get time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED:**

```
Sub Test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = ws.Rows(4).Cells.Find("XXX").Offset(0, -1)

Range(rng.Offset(0, 1).Address).SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkLine, SourceData:=Range("D4" & ":" & rng.Address).Address

End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  I got this message.  Run-time error '1004':                  Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed

Comment: What line did it fail on? Did you add your range in `yourRange`?

Comment: `wb.ws.Range.Rows(4).Cells.Find("XXX").Offset(0, -1).SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkLine, SourceData:=Range("D4" & ":" & rng)` This is all one line.

Comment: Try copying and pasting mine.

Comment: Your picture helped, too. Try it now.

Comment: Same error.  I pasted yours into mine and everything looks to match when I look at it.  In the Debugger when I hold over the Range for the `SourceData:=Range("D4" & ":" & rng)` is where it says there is an error.

Comment: My apologies. I tested the above this time and it works. I tested it with your attachment so it should be fine this time. :)

Comment: okay that worked.  Would you mind explaining what adding `.Address` did.  Thanks very much!

Comment: `.Address` returns a string that represents the range. Without it you get the value in the range instead of where the value lives.